# Compare word to Text file Java

Tags: java, string, swing, while-loop, buffer

we are supposed to create a program that reads a word from a JTextField and compare it to a list, then we have to count how many lines to the word if it exist and display the same line from another text file in the same program into another JTextField (it's supposed to be a Dictionary of some sort) here is what i have:

```
boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
String palabra=tx1.getText();
boton3.setEnabled(true);
try{
        // here is where i open my file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src/archivos/translator.txt");
        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
        String strLinea;
        while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
              System.out.println (strLinea);
        int i=0;
        while (!(strLinea.equals(palabra))){
        i++;

        }
  tx2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        entrada.close();
    }catch (IOException x){ 
        System.err.println("Oh no, ocurrió un error: " + x.getMessage());
    }
```

}} );

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you said, first, you should change:

```
while (!(strLinea.equals(palabra))){
```

to

```
while (!(strLinea.contains(palabra))){
```

You want to see if the line contains that word, not that the line is the same as the contents of the `TextArea`. Also, you'll want to add another statement to the contents of that while loop. Currently it'll just increment "i" forever if the word doesn't come up in the document. You want it to move strLinea to the next line if the current one doesn't have it, and if it does, you'll then want to terminate the loop.

Comment: I want to see if the line matches with the word and then if it does i want to know in wich line of my text files is it and then print the same line number from another text file into another TextArea. i´ve been working on it all day and i can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Okay, so you want to see if the entire line is the same as that from the TextArea? If so ".equals" is fine, and inside your while loop with "i++" you'll want to make sure you move to the next line there, tracking the number of lines you moved through. Then put a loop iterating up to that value, so if the number of lines was i=155, you'd go up to i=155 in the other loop, moving to the next line in the other document. Then take the correct line there and put it in the other TextArea you want.

Comment: Thanks i have no reputation yet, so i can't upvote you but you helped me a lot :)

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind the hazard of using ".equals" for this: if there's an extra space somewhere or anything, it won't return that line. ".contains" will be much safer, especially if you're looking for a word or a couple of words.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is

```
while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
          System.out.println (strLinea);
    int i=0;
    while (!(strLinea.equals(palabra))){
    i++;

    }
tx2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

In inner *while* loop, you are iterating forever. If you want to compare each word in the file to the JTextField value, you should write

```
int i = 0;   
while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
    i++;
    System.out.println (i + " " + strLinea);
    if (strLinea.equals(palabra)){
        tx2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I cant upvote yet, (i have no rep) but you really helped me a lot